# Alert box goes away on cancel but comes back again to haunt?

Tags: android, multithreading

All i want to do is display a text for 1000 milliseconds and get the next thing.. dialogs are slow to pop up so i used a textview..but its not working.. the code snippet is given.. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
Thread sleep_for_sometime = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        correct.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                        sleep(1000);
                        correct.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        get_question(questionset[i]);
                    }
                }
            };
            //sleep_for_sometime.setDaemon(false);
            sleep_for_sometime.start();
```

Comment: How is it not working? It's showing up _after_ you call `correct.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE)`?

Comment: Its getting the next question and crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Nikita's Answer , you could do something like this

```
private class SleepTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                publishProgress(0);
                sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(1);
            }catch(Exception e){
                //null
                }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i){
            if(i[0]==0){
                correct.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                correct.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
            get_question(questionset[i]);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //do something before execution
    }
}
```

to start the thread , do this

```
new SleepTask().execute();
```

Comment: I really cant use sleep without creating a thread..so should I create one inside?

Comment: Hey I put the thread and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I want to compare the performance so i want to use trace view..how do i get that? how do i got the sdk tools ?

Answer (score 3):

You should change visibility in UI thread. Read [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: I want to compare the performance so i want to use trace view..how do i get that? how do i get the sdk tools/directory in eclipse ?

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` is great, but overused in some ways I think. Just use `post`/`postDelayed`. You're not really doing background work, you just want to delay some UI-thread work. Definitely read Nikita's link, but I would do something like:

```
correct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
correct.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    correct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    get_question(questionset[i]);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: correct is a textview object..It doesn't have a postdelayed methods